# Is there any way to extend ASP.NET Membership Provider?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I want to extend static class `public static class Membership` and `public abstract class MembershipProvider` is there any way i can do that?

Answer (score 5):

See [Implementing a Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) on MSDN for a full and detailed explanation of how to create a custom membership provider by inheriting from `MembershipProvider`. As far as the static `Membership` class, there would be no point to extending it; you can't override static methods. And it just delegates to an instance of `MembershipProvider` anyways, so you don't want to extend the `Membership` class, you just want to setup your configuration so that your new MembershipProvider gets called.

Answer (score 0):

For those who do want to extend existing providers, something like:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace System.Web.MVC_Extensions
{
    public static class SqlMembershipProviderExtensions
    {
        public static string GenerateAccessToken(this MembershipProvider provider, string username, int expiresInMinutes)
        {
            if (provider.GetType().Name != "SqlMembershipProvider")
                throw new NotSupportedException("Access tokens only supported by SqlMembershipProvider.");

            ...
        }

        public static bool ValidateAccessToken(this MembershipProvider provider, string username, string token)
        {
            if (provider.GetType().Name != "SqlMembershipProvider")
                throw new NotSupportedException("Access tokens only supported by SqlMembershipProvider.");

            ...
        }
    }
}
```